# What's going on in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
for a,b,c in x,y,z:
    print(a,b,c)
```

The output is :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I can't mentally navigate whatever logic is going on here to produce this output. I am aware of the zip function to make this code behave in the way I clearly intend it to; but I'm just trying to understand why it works this way when you don't use the zip function.

Is this a deliberate functionality, a feature, that you can successively iterate through multiple lists this way? Sort of?

Comment: "the way I clearly intend"?  LOL - I have no idea what you intend here ;-)

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants `1 4 7` etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have good answers already, but I think considering this equivalent variation will help to make it clearer:

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
for t in x,y,z:
    a, b, c = t
    print(a,b,c)
```

You're not surprised that `t` is successively bound to `x`, `y` and `z`, right?  Exactly the same thing is happening in your original code, except that the:

```
a, b, c = t
```

part isn't as obvious.

Comment: I had to read `a, b, c = t` (which is just weird to read at first) like three times, but then it clicked.

Comment: Great!  I figured that was the part that was the real source of the confusion, so broke it out into its own line.  Now you'll never be surprised by anything ever again ;-)

Comment: EVER, in ANY field of knowledge that I choose to explore. I'll always remember tonight as the night it all turned around for me.

Answer (score 6):

Oh man this is a mess. This is simply too much use of python's [iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). The statement `a, b, c = iterable` simply assigns the elements of `iterable` to the variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. In this case `iterable` must have 3 elements.

First you have:

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
# Which is:
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = [7, 8, 9]
```

then you have:

```
for a, b, c in x, y, z:
    print(a, b, c)
# Which is:
temp = (x, y, z)
for item in temp:
    a = item[0]
    b = item[1]
    c = item[2]
    print(a, b, c)
```

One more thing to note is that the statement `mytuple = 1, 2, 3` is the same as `mytuple = (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: This answer in conjunction with Tim Peters' answer makes it crystal clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty straight forward code really.

1. This assigns the three lists to `x`, `y`, and `z`.

   ```
   x,y,z = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
   ```
2. This creates a tuple of `(x,y,z)` and will iterate over each element.

   ```
   for a,b,c in x,y,z:
   ```

   However, the `a,b,c` means that the iterables are expected to have 3 objects
3. Then, this prints `a`,`b` and `c`.

   ```
       print(a,b,c)
   ```

If you want to see what is happening, I'd suggest altering one of the elements in `y`:

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3], [3,4,5,6], [7,8,9]
for a,b,c in x,y,z:
    print(a,b,c)

1 2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Or, by removing one from `x`:

```
x,y,z = [1,2], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
for a,b,c in x,y,z:
    print(a,b,c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Comment: With Tim's answer, It is better clear to me, last example are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
```

is the same as saying

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
z = [7,8,9]
```

Next

```
for a,b,c in x,y,z:
```

is equivalent to

```
for a,b,c in [x,y,z]:
```

which just says "take `x`, `y` and `z` in turn. Assign their contents, respectively to `a`, `b` and `c`; i.e. `a=x[0]`, `b=x[1]`, `c=x[2]`.
Ultimately, this turns into

```
a,b,c = x
print(a,b,c)
a,b,c = y
print(a,b,c)
a,b,c = z
print(a,b,c)
```

Comment: much helpful but I think `for a,b,c in [x,y,z]:` should be written as `for a, b, c in (x, y, z):`, I mean tuple instead of list,  No?

Answer (score 2):

It is an unusual python thing. The implicit creation of tuple.

Here, you create an anonymous tuple at the right

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
```

This is a similar code:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

that is the same:

```
a, b =  (1, 2)
```

or

```
   a = 1
   b = 2
```

It allows a common python trick (idiom). You can swap values without an temporary variable:

```
a, b = b, a
```

The same happens interacting the key and values of a dictionary:

```
for i, j in  my_dict.items():
   print i, j
```

In your code, the another temporary tuple is being created in the for loop:

```
for a,b,c in (x,y,z):
    print(a,b,c)
```

That means:

```
for a, b,c in ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]):
    print(a,b,c)
```

In other words: rewrite this code for something more legible. Python isn't following its own mantra: *Explicit is better than implicit.*.

BTW, see the fun Python Zen typing `import this` in a Python shell.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

The first part is realizing that commas implicitly create tuples. So the first line is equivalent to:

```
x,y,z = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
```

This also means that your for loop is equivalent to:

```
for a,b,c in ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]):
```

The second part to understand is sequence unpacking. This means that if you assign a sequence of length `n` to `n` variables, Python assigns the items in the sequence appropriately. So the first part is effectively:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
z = [7,8,9]
```

And the for loop is the same as:

```
for t in (x,y,z):
   a = t[0]
   b = t[1]
   c = t[2]
   print(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 3 arrays

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
z = [7,8,9]
```

and a,b,c represent the elements in each array.  So it looks like the for loop is iterating over 3 arrays and mapping the elements to a,b, and c.  Then printing them out.  Then again, I don't know python